# Vapniks proof of the basic lemma

Tags: machine-learning, svm

In his book *Statistical Learning Theory* (1998), Vladimir Vapnik proves an inequality needed to prove a bound on the risk for indicator loss functions. Theorem 4.1 
on page 133 he derives the following inequalities

$$I \ge \int_{Z_2} [\nu(\alpha^*,Z_2)-P(\alpha^*)-1/l]dF(Z_2)=P \left[\nu(\alpha^*,Z_2)\ge P(\alpha^*)^{-1/2} \right]$$
$$=\sum C_l^kP(\alpha^*)^k[1-P(\alpha^*)]^{l-k}$$

I absolutely don't get these two equalities.
Furthermore, I think in the first integral there should be a $+ 1 / l$

Is anybody able to give me some idea?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
EDIT:

I NOW HAVE A REFORMULATION OF THIS PROOF MADE BY VAPNIK IN MY OWN WORDS AND NOTATION. THE LAST INEQUALITIES ARE MY PROBLEM

Let $Z(2l)$ be the spaces of random selections of magnitude 2l. A element of this space we call $Z^{2l}=\left(z_1,\ldots,z_l,z_{l+1},\ldots,z_{2l}\right)$.\
For a loss function $\{ L(z,\alpha) \} _{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ we calculate the empirical risk $R_{emp}^{(1)} (\alpha) = \frac{1}{l} \sum_{i=1}^{l}L(z_i,\alpha)$ on $Z_1 = \left(z_1,\ldots,z_l  \right)$ and the empirical risk $R_{emp}^{(2)} (\alpha) = \frac{1}{l} \sum_{i=l+1}^{2l}L(z_i,\alpha)$ on $Z_2 = \left(z_{l+1},\ldots,z_{2l}  \right)$ von $Z^{2l}$.
We define the random variables:
$$\rho^\Lambda(\alpha, Z^{2l}) := | R_{emp}^{(1)}(\alpha)-R_{emp}^{(2)}(\alpha) |$$
 $$\rho^\Lambda(Z^{2l}):= \sup \limits_{\alpha \in \Lambda} \rho^\Lambda (\alpha,Z^{2l})$$
 $$\pi^\Lambda(\alpha,Z_1):= |R(\alpha)-R_{emp}^{(1)}(\alpha)|$$
$$\pi^\Lambda (Z_1):= \sup\limits_{\alpha\in\Lambda} \pi^\Lambda (\alpha,Z_2)
$$
and assume $\pi^\Lambda (Z_1)$ and $\rho^\Lambda (Z^{2l})$ being measurable with respect to the probability measure $P$ generating the data.
We want to show:
  $$P \left \{ \pi^\Lambda (Z_1) > \epsilon   \right\} < 2 P\left\{ \rho^\Lambda (Z^{2l}) > \epsilon - \frac{1}{l}   \right\}$$

By definition there exists $\epsilon_*:=\epsilon-\frac{1}{l}$
 such that
  $$P \left \{ \rho^\Lambda(Z^{2l}) > \epsilon_*   \right\}=\int_{Z(2l)} 1\left[ \rho^\Lambda (Z^{2l}) >\epsilon_*  \right] dF(Z^{2l})\\=\int_{Z_1} dF(Z_1) \int_{Z_2} 1\left[\rho^\Lambda (Z^{2l}) > \epsilon_*\right]dF(Z_2)$$
Let $Q$ be the event:
$$ Q:= \left\{ Z_1 : \pi^\Lambda (Z_1) > \epsilon  \right\}$$
We get
$$ P \left \{ \rho^\Lambda(Z^{2l}) > \epsilon_*   \right\} \geq \int_Q dF(Z_1)\underbrace{ \int_{Z_2(l)} 1 \left[ \rho^\Lambda (Z^{2l}) > \epsilon* \right] dF(Z_2) } _{Int}$$
We now examine the integral $Int$. Here $Z_1$ is fixed with $\pi^\Lambda (Z_1) > \epsilon$. That is why there exists $\alpha^* \in \Lambda$ such that

$$ |P(\alpha^*) - R_{emp}^{(1)}(\alpha^*)|>\epsilon $$ for
 $$P(\alpha^*)=\int L(z,\alpha^*) dF(z)$$ with
 $$L(z,\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}|y-f(x,\alpha)|$$ then is
$$Int = \int_{Z_2} 1\left[ \sup\limits_{\alpha\in\Lambda} \rho(\alpha, Z^{2l}) > \epsilon_*  \right] dF(Z_2)\\
\geq \int_{Z_2} 1\left[ \rho(\alpha^*, Z^{2l}) > \epsilon_*  \right] dF(Z_2)
$$
Without loss of generality we assume now $R_{emp}^{(1)}(\alpha^*)<P(\alpha^*)-\epsilon$  such that
$$R_{emp}^{(2)}(\alpha^*) \geq P(\alpha^*)-\frac{1}{l}$$ is sufficient for
$$\rho(\alpha^*, Z^{2l})=| R_{emp}^{(1)}(\alpha^*)-R_{emp}^{(2)}(\alpha^*)| > \epsilon_* $$

and we get
$$
 Int \geq \int_{Z_2} 1 \left[ \ R_{emp}^{(2)}(\alpha^*) \geq P(\alpha^*)-\frac{1}{l}  \right]dF(Z_2)\\
 = P \left\{ R_{emp}^{(2)}(\alpha^*) \geq P^{-1/2}(\alpha^*)  \right\}\\
 = \sum_{\frac{k}{l} \geq P(\alpha^*) - \frac{1}{l}} \binom{l}{k} \left[ P(\alpha^*) \right]^k \left[ 1-P(\alpha^*)\right]^{l-k}\\
 > \frac{1}{2}$$
resubstituting yields
\begin{align*}
  P \left \{ \rho^\Lambda(Z^{2l}) > \epsilon_*   \right\} > \frac{1}{2} \int_Q dF(Z_1)= \frac{1}{2} P\left\{ \pi^\Lambda (Z_1) > \epsilon  \right\}
\end{align*}
qed

Comment: In its present state this question cannot be understood without having access to the text.  You will greatly increase your chances of obtaining informative answers if you would edit this question to explain what the various symbols mean.

Comment: yes indeed this post is adressed only to people able to access this book. The proof i refer to is really lengthy, so it would be pretty hard to state it completely, especially because i had to explain all the notation and I do not know how to include LaTex style formulas. Maybe i can include some pdf in my next post. ANYWAY...thanks for trying to help!